# How to get all strings matching wildcards from word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, find, office-interop

I am trying to write an application to search a word document for all occurrences of , where some_text is any string of characters between < and >.  As I find each match, I'd like to store/display/do something with each one.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Word._Application word = new Word.Application();
Word.Documents d = word.Documents;
Word._Document doc;

doc = d.Open(strFileName);
doc.Activate();

foreach (Word.Range myStoryRange in doc.StoryRanges)
{
    myStoryRange.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
    myStoryRange.Find.Text = "[<]*[>]";
    myStoryRange.Find.Execute();

    // Somehow get the result string that matched the wildcard
}
```

Comment: can't you use regex? don't you have access to the pure text of the Word document?

Comment: Was there an answer disguised in your reply somewhere?  You are basically asking me the question I just asked in my question.  I don't know how to access the pure text of the Word document.

Comment: no there is no answered disguised :> I just thought it is more efficient and easier to use regex. But if you don't have access to the pure text, then that's a different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Range is re-defined for each found string.  You can access each found text as:

```
rng.Text
```

And you can get the found text character positions within the greater Range:

```
rng.Start
rng.End
```

So I was able to do this by declaring a local Range containing only the found string within the Find loop.  I was replacing each text with a DocProperty, but you could do anything you like with it:

```
    Word.Range rng = this.Content;
    rng.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
    rng.Find.Text = "[<]*[>]";

    while (rng.Find.Execute())
    {
        // create a local Range containing only a single found string
        object cstart = rng.Start;
        object cend   = rng.End;
        Word.Range localrng = this.Range(ref cstart, ref cend);

        // replace the text with a custom DocProperty
        Word.Field newfld = localrng.Fields.Add(localrng, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDocProperty, "MyDocProp", false);
        localrng.Fields.Update();
    }
```